# SQL Error in displaying long/lat from .csv

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, error, latitude-longitude

I tried to display long/lat (°) as points from a .csv but an

ArcMap drawing Error occurs:

> One or more layers failed to draw:
>
> 2016-07-29_GPS_Collar09743_20160729125522.csv Events:  An invalid SQL
>   statement was used.

My Data look like:

[image]

And this is the Display XY Data Window

[image]

What am I doing wrong if i want it to draw in WGS 84 ?

After the correction suggested by JGH it looks like this:

[image]

And if I use the Identify tool:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates in degree not meter? There is a a comma separator which implies that the numbers are in thousands. If you are sure it is in geographic latitude and longitude, you need to change the separator in the numbers from comma `(,)` to dot `(.)` and use Geographic CRS (WGS84). Also, I see the numbers in longitude are repeated, for example the first and second numbers in longitude are same.

Comment: Your map (data frame) must be using WGS 1984 UTM Zone 34N so the Add XY tool defaults to the same coordinate system. You must change it to a geographic coordinate system like WGS 1984 because the coordinates are in degrees, not linear units.

Comment: ahmadhanb was right, so it is dec degrees but with wgs 1984 in the dataframe I end up in arabia... not poland where they should be. thanks so far

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, the field name is probably creating the issue. Try changing it from `longitude [°]` to `longitude` (i.e. a single word without special character).

Once this is fixed, you will likely want to change the coordinate system as your coordinates are not in meters but in degrees, so UTM is not good. You will want to select `Geographic Coordinate Systems / World / WGS 1984`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the points are not displayed correctly (layer and dataframe are WGS1984). It looks like the picture I added to the end of my Question.

Comment: @tobisito please provide more details... what make you think the points are not at the proper place?

Comment: if I add to a basemap and zoom the area where they were recorded, I cannot see them. Also is the basemap missing if I zoom to the eventlayer with the points

Comment: @tobisito so what are the XY coordinates (as seen in ArcMap)?

Comment: they are way to "large" as you can see in the picture added to bottom of the question

Comment: :-) a bit too large indeed. On the last screenshot, there are no more decimals for the lat/long. See @ahmadhanb comment

Comment: @tobisito As this post addresses your original question (error message when creating the points), please consider accepting the answer (green check mark to the left) so others know it is a working solution

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer of JGH. I also noticed that your coordinates are not correct. Try changing by notepad the separator comma (,) to Point (.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok everyone sorry for wasting your time. so the units were decimal degrees and for some reason the heading was mixed up. so when I changed the x and y it worked perfectly -.-